# python regex matching paragraph(s) starting with labels

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a paragraph or paragraphs which are lead by letters.  I'm testing on  and have tried dotALL, lookaheads, multiline, etc and I can't seem to get one to work.  The string I'm trying to match looks like this:

```
      A-B:  Object, procedure:
      - Somethings.
      - More things, might run over several lines like this where the sentence just keeps on going and going and going and sometimes isn't even a sentence.
      - Another line, sometimes not ending with period
      - Variable amount of white space at the beginning of new lines

       Comment (A-B): sometimes, there are comments which are separated by two \n\n characters like this.*

      C.  Second object, other procedure:
      - More lines.
      - Can have various leads (including no ' - ' leading.
      - Variable number of lines.
```

The closest I've come to a match was using '(.+?\n\n|.+?$)' and dotALL (which I realize is sloppy), but even this didn't work because it misses comments or paragraphs separated by more lines but still under the header ([A-Z]?-?[A-Z]).

Ideally I'd like to capture the header or title (A-B:) or (C.) in match.group(1) and the rest of the paragraphs(s) before the next title in match.group(2), but I'd just be happy to capture everything. I tried lookaheads to catch everything between titles, but that misses the last instance which won't have a title at the end.

I'm a newb and I apologize if this has already been answered or if I'm not clear (but I have been looking for the past 2 days without success). Thanks!

Comment: Realized I hadn't included that... it's been fixed in an edit.

Comment: MAYBE you just need a loop? since you know how to detect headers, just see if each line is a header, if not then it is a member of the last header.

Comment: @YongkangZhao I like that idea. Could you give a code example on how to do it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance The comments should be separated from the heading line by at least one line of text as in the example. The head should start with a single letter with optional dash and second letter.  Comments would start with a word (usually comment or note or something). There should NOT be anything like this:
A. Object, something:
Comment (A): This is a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
(^[^\n]+)(?:\n *-.+(?:\n.+)*|\n\n.+\n)+
```

- `(^[^\n]+)` - Match the header line, then repeatedly alternate between
- `\n *-.+(?:\n.+)*` - A non-comment line: starts with whitespace, followed by `-`, optionally running across multiple lines
- `\n\n.+\n` - Or, match a comment line

(no dotall flag)

https://regex101.com/r/6kle0u/2

This depends on the comment lines always having `\n\n` before them.

Comment: This works in the link you sent above, but not in pythex.org or in my code and I can't figure out why.  Based on this code, I tried the following: ([A-Z]{1,2}|[A-Z]-[A-Z])(?::|\.)\s+(\w.+)(.*\n+?)+\s+(?=([A-Z]{1,2}(?:\.|:))).  This allows me to capture the header letter(s) which I need, and also the header text (which is nice), but it breaks for the last entity.  Anyone know of a way to make it look ahead to another header and if it doesn't find one, just match what's left? I tried an or '|' but that breaks the look ahead and makes it greedy (try to capture parts of the second entity).

Comment: Make sure to enable the multiline flag, so that `^` matches the start of a new line.

Answer (score 0):

so here is my proposed solution for you :)

```
import re
with open('./samplestring.txt') as f:
    header =[]
    nonheader = []
    yourString = f.read()
    for line in content.splitlines():
        if(re.match('(^[A-Z]?-?[A-Z]:)|(^[A-Z]\.)',line.lstrip())):
            header.append(line)
        else:
            nonheader.append(line)
```

Comment: This is brilliant, and I thought it would work, but when I tried to code it, I realized that the string is in a list because I'm looping through a document with many different areas that have this syntax. I tried splitting the list into strings using a for loop but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up on capturing comments and everything after them. I used the following code to capture the letter for each header (group(1)), the text for the header (group(2)), and the text in the paragraph excluding comments (group(3)).

([A-Z]{1,2}|[A-Z]-[A-Z])(?::|.) +(\w.+)\n+((\s*(- *.+))+)

([A-Z]{1,2}|[A-Z]-[A-Z])(?::|.) +
captures the letter (group 1), the colon or period, and the space(s) after that

(\w.+)\n+
captures the text of the header, and the next line(s)

((\s*(- *.+))+)
captures multiple lines starting variably with a space, dash, space, and text

I appreciate all your help with this! :)